# Access Token encryption After 1st October

Tags: facebook, authentication, encryption, token

Will the encryption of the token be in place for apps registered before the 1st of september? 
will it be possible to disable the encryption of the token using the advanced setting as it is?

We need to understand if the release in production will be affected by the change and if we'll have a possible workaround?

Up to now all the application created before the 1st of september are working fine, but the code doesn't expect and encrypted token..

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will affect everyone, so you will need to update your app(s) to work with the change.

"All apps must migrate to OAuth 2.0 for authentication and expect an encrypted access token. The old SDKs, including the old JS SDK and old iOS SDK will no longer work."

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Comment: Mhh thanks,

what about stored token, will they continue to work or they will receive an invalid token exception?

thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by stored token? If you mean the one in the cookie, you will need to be able to decode the new cookie format to use this too. There is a 'How to migrate' section here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/

Comment: Hi there, well.. my understanding is that, if the user assign an offline permission to the application, the token never expires, unless the user change the password.. for our application we'll have non encrypted tokens stored so I was wondering if those users will be affected.. or the token will continue to work. thanks

Comment: offline_access will work the same way. But when you get a new token for someone, it will be encrypted. So you need to decrypt it before saving, if you want to save the unencrypted token.